# Calculating the GC content of a list of sequences individually

Tags: python-3.x, bioinformatics

I have a list of sequences and I am trying to calculate the GC content in a percentage (meaning what percent of the sequence are the letters 'G','g','C','c')

```
#series of sequences
seq0,seq1,seq2,seq3,seq4,seq5 = 'CCACGCGTCCGCCGCGACCTGCGTTTTCCTGGGGGTCCGCAACTCTGGCTTGACCCAAGGACCCGGCCAC','attgccattatataACCCGGCCACCCCCATAGGCAGATGTCAGGACAACTCGCATCTCAGCAGAGCAGCCCCTGGCCCAGG','TCXCACCCATAGGCAGATGGCCTCCGCCCCACCCCCGGGAGGATTTCTTAATGGGGTGAAAATGC','CAGTCCCCGAAGCCAGGGTTCCGGGACCCCCGGGGCCGAGCTGGGCGCGGGAAAAGAAttacggacttaGTCAGCCCCGCAGGGG','ATGGGGTGATCGTCGCTCGCGGGCTCTGTCTTCCTGTTCACCCTCCTCTGCCCCCAACTCCATCTCTGAGACCTCCTGCCCCCCCA','AAAAAAGAAGTCGCTCGCGTCGCTCGCGGGCTGGGCTCTGTCTGCGTCGCTCGCGGGCTAGAGAGCCAGGGTGA'

#sequences aggregated into a list
NTs = [seq0,seq1,seq2,seq3,seq4,seq5]

#specifying nucleotides
nucleotides = ['G','A','C','T', 'U']

#checking and removing if there are any non-nucleotide characters present
if any(x not in nucleotides for x in NTs):
     print("ERROR: non-nucleotide characters present")
[''.join(i for i in x if i.upper() in nucleotides) for x in NTs]

 #calculating GC percent of each sequence using the aggregated list
 gCountseq0 = seq0.count('G') + seq0.count('g')
 cCountseq0 = seq0.count('C') + seq0.count('c')
 gcContentseq0 = ((gCountseq0 + cCountseq0)*100) / len(seq0)
 print('The GC content of seq0 is',gcContentseq0,'%')
```

from this I just get the output

```
ERROR: non-nucleotide characters present
The GC content of seq0 is 70.0 %
```

Eventually I'm trying to get something that looks like the output below but i'm a bit stuck, and I don't know how to pass off the NTs list as the argument for GC% calculation so I can do all of the sequences at once instead of each one individually

```
ERROR: non-nucleotide characters present in seq2
The GC content of seq0 is x %
The GC content of seq1 is x %
The GC content of seq2 is x %
The GC content of seq3 is x %
The GC content of seq4 is x %
The GC content of seq5 is x %
```

Comment: Do you mean `for`? see: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate thought your list of sequences (NTs) in loop and calculate GC contend on each iteration.

This is function for GC calculation:

```
def GC_calc(fa_string):
    _string = fa_string.upper()
    _G = _string.count('G')
    _C = _string.count('C')
    return (_G + _C)/len(_string) * 100
```

This is a loop:

```
for i,j in zip(names, NTs):
    print(f'The GC content of {i} is {GC_calc(j)} %')
```

Here I use `zip` function to iterate through names and sequences in same time. I think it is better way. Do do this you should add `list` of sequences names in the `zip` function.

```
names = ['seq_name_1', 'seq_name_2']
```